# imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo issue

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

What is the result if I didn't edit the picture?

```
(image = nil ? or image = OriginalImage) 

picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

Comment: Why not build a sample (5-10 min at most) and run it yourself to check?

Comment: i cann't test today. I need a real iphone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either the key would not exist in the dictionary or it would be the same as the original image. The easiest thing to do is just to code defensively:

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
if (!image) image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

That way you'll still get sane results even if the behavior is different on different versions of iOS.